# Cipher: Find the murderer

Tags: cipher, mystery

Bob was killed by someone.

This is what you found at the crime scene:

> the person who ended bob's life is Iapes Ehzn
>
> also, the person is Ictlb Puod

Jolin Hera

Rivka Mond

Hyman Yarn

Chari Davi

Ellis Chan

Comment: What are the names listed below the quoted text? The possible suspects? Also, why the [optimization] tag?

Comment: yes, and I was looking for a mystery tag, but I misclicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The murderer is

> Hyman Yarn

because

> if you move the $n$th letter in "Hyman Yarn" ahead by $n$ places in the alphabet (wrapping round from Z to A if necessary), you get "Iapes Ehzn". At least, this works for all but the last letter - possibly the OP made a mistake with that one?

Check:

> H -> I
>  Y -> Z -> A
>  M -> N,O -> P
>  A -> B,C,D -> E
>  N -> O,P,Q,R -> S
>  Y -> Z,A,B,C,D -> E
>  A -> B,C,D,E,F,G -> H
>  R -> S,T,U,V,W,X,Y -> Z
>  N -> N (?)

Thanks to [mr23ceec](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44175/cipher-find-the-murderer/44177?noredirect=1#comment132776_44177), "Ictlb Puod" also fits the same person because

> if you move the $n$th letter in "Hyman Yarn" ahead by $3n-2$ places in the alphabet, you get "Ictlb Puod", with some letters out by exactly one place (maybe the OP miscounted?) and again the last letter not quite working.

Check:

> H -> I
>  Y -> Z,A,B -> C
>  M -> N,O,P,Q,R,S -> T
>  A -> B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J -> <strike>K</strike> L
>  N -> O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z -> <strike>A</strike> B
>  Y -> Z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N -> <strike>O</strike> P
>  A -> B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S -> <strike>T</strike> U
>  R -> S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M -> <strike>N</strike> O
>  N -> D?

Comment: There was probably a BMYguest puzzle with some circles which probably used same encryption.

Comment: By the same token, Ictlb Puod is [That person] starting at -1, with step -3.

Comment: @mr23ceec Well, almost ...

Comment: That's what I got for Ictlb Puod but threw it out coz it didn't quite work out. There's _sort of_ a pattern.